# How do I refactor this controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, refactoring

I have a Project model which has many groups. A Group has many users through a Membership model. A project must have at least one group. When creating a new project, I must create its default group, and make the current user a member.

I don't want to use ActiveRecord callbacks, but I would be interested in seeing how a solution using them would work. I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to create the project and the default group.

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)
  if @project.save
    @project.groups.first.members << current_user
    redirect_to @project
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

There are three problems with this action:

1. No transaction. The user may not get added to the project's default group.
2. This line `@project.groups.first.members << current_user` should not be in a controller.
3. It uses `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. I prefer not to use it, but I will continue to if I have to.

Comment: use the service object - http://ericfarkas.com/posts/recent-experience-with-service-objects-in-rails/

Comment: I don't see a problem with putting some variation of (2) in a controller, or using (3). (1) is a bit of an issue though.

Comment: @sevenseacat can you elaborate on `some variation` please?

Comment: well, ideally it would be something like `current_user.projects.new`. I'm not sure how your associations tie together though.

Answer (score 0):

project.rb

```
def add_new_user(user_id)
  self.groups.first.members << User.find_by_id(user_id)
  self.groups.first.members.count == 1
end
```

controller.rb

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)
  if @project.save && @project.add_new_user(current_user.id)
    redirect_to @project
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```